# table-cell width not working on chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I am working on page - http://wordpress-beta.worldnow.com/revenue-solution/ where if you scroll down little bit you will see a second navigation menu. On this navigation menu I have set width of `a` as 33.33% but it not working on chrome where as it working on firefox.

```
ul#menu-revenue-service-menu li a {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

How should I fix this problem in chrome?

Comment: It won't work because the `li` is a table cell of 33% as well. Maybe you'd get the desired effect if you make the `a` display inline-block?

Comment: @RenéGeuze If I make `a` as inline-block then I am not getting vertically centered text

Comment: @AlexChar it is not working in chrome and safari

Comment: You could use the same technique that you use for the ul/li sizing but you'd just need another div wrapper that functions as table.`<li=tcell><div=table><a=tcell>text</a></div></li>`. And there are plenty of other techniques to vertically center a single line of text.